Add a Icon in density_mapbox
i want to put a store icon in my map, but i dont find how to do that, i just make my heatmap, but to finished i want to put this store icons. the code is bellow

import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

d = {'Location': ['Point A', 'Point B'], 'lat': [30, 40], 'long': [-90, -80], 'z': [100,200]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

fig = px.density_mapbox(df
                        ,lat='lat'
                        ,lon='long'
                        ,z='z'
                        ,hover_name='Location'
                        ,center=dict(lat=38.5, lon=-96)
                        ,range_color = [0, 200]
                        ,zoom=2
                        ,radius=50
                        ,opacity=.5
                        ,mapbox_style='open-street-map')

fig.add_scattermapbox(lat = [30, 40]
                      ,lon = [-90, -80]
                      ,hoverinfo = 'none'
                      ,marker_size = 6
                      ,marker_color = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
                      ,marker_symbol = 'star'
                      ,showlegend = True
                     )

fig.show()

I want to know how make this point´s in my map, and how to choose my icon!
